# System.Data.Odbc Not being referenced

Tags: c#, odbc, openedge, progress-db

I'm trying to connect to a progress database but get a

> Type or namespace cannot be found (are you...)

I understand that I need to reference the name space with 'using'. However, the class is still not picking up the reference. See code below:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Odbc; // Reference Here
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace DatabaseClassLibrary
{
  public static class ProgressDB
  {
    static string connstr;

    static ProgressDB ()
    {
       connstr = "DSN=" + ...;

    }

    public static bool TestConnection ()
    {
       // Error @ OdbcConnection 
       using (OdbcConnection dbConn = new OdbcConnection(connstr)) 
       {
         ...
       }

       return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Additional Information
I am building a DotNetCore 2 application. However, this part is in a separate class library project. The documentation can be found here: [Progress Knowledgebase](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P107401)

Comment: namespace reference works when correct dll is referenced and it can read the assembly metadata, here it seems to be not able to get correct assembly reference

Comment: So your class library is a .NET Core project too, I assume.  The Odbc provider types are in System.Data.dll in the .NET Framework but in .NET Core I believe that they are in System.Data.Odbc.dll, so you'd have to reference that assembly before you can import that namespace.

Comment: The [`OdbcConnection` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.data.odbc.odbcconnection?view=netframework-4.7.1) indicates that it is supported in .NET Core 2.0 and it also indicates that there is a System.Data.Odbc.dll assembly at the top of the page. I just created a .NET Core 2.0 Class Library project and I can add System.Data.SqlClient using NuGet but there doesn't seem to be a System.Data.Odbc package. Not sure what the story is, to be honest.